# Kivy. Don't show checkbox on android

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I created checkbox in .kv file on Desktop kivy app and It shows normally. But on android device I don't see It.I tried tap of all points on screen and whatever dont see It. In logcat there is no errors.
What problem can happened?

This is part of .kv file

```
Widget:
    FloatLayout:
            CheckBox:
            color:1,0,0,0
            on_active: app.checkActive2(*args)
            pos_hint:{'top': 5, 'center_x':4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Руслан. Try this code:

```
FloatLayout:
    CheckBox:
        size_hint: None, None # for setting the size
        size: 20, 20
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1 # Red-Blue-Green-Alpha
        on_active: print("Hello from Mr. Checkbox")
        pos_hint:{'top': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.4}
```

You are using `pos_hint` incorrectly. It should be a value from 0 to 1. Like this: `pos_hint: {'top': 0.5, 'center_x': 0.4}`. You are also setting the checkbox alpha to 0 (fully transparent), it should be 1.